# Can't install tidyverse package in R version 3.5.2

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to install the tidyverse package and not being able to do it.
1-tried via Packages -> Install
2-tried from console->   install.packages("tidyverse")

Gives errors as below and therefore not loading the lirary

```r
> library(tidyverse)
Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’

Console Errors:
****************************************************************************************


> install.packages("tidyverse")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘lifecycle’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘vctrs’, ‘gargle’, ‘glue’, ‘rematch2’, ‘scales’, ‘ellipsis’, ‘vroom’, ‘tzdb’, ‘broom’, ‘cli’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘dplyr’, ‘dtplyr’, ‘googledrive’, ‘googlesheets4’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘haven’, ‘hms’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘lubridate’, ‘magrittr’, ‘modelr’, ‘pillar’, ‘readr’, ‘rlang’, ‘rvest’, ‘tibble’, ‘tidyr’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions
  are later:
              binary source needs_compilation
lifecycle      0.2.0  1.0.1             FALSE
tidyselect     1.0.0  1.1.1              TRUE
vctrs          0.2.4  0.3.8              TRUE
gargle         0.4.0  1.2.0             FALSE
glue           1.4.0  1.4.2              TRUE
rematch2       2.1.0  2.1.2             FALSE
scales         1.1.0  1.1.1             FALSE
ellipsis       0.3.0  0.3.2              TRUE
vroom          1.2.0  1.5.5              TRUE
broom          0.5.6  0.7.9             FALSE
cli            2.0.2  3.0.1              TRUE
dbplyr         1.4.3  2.1.1             FALSE
dplyr          0.8.5  1.0.7              TRUE
dtplyr         1.0.1  1.1.0             FALSE
googledrive    1.0.0  2.0.0             FALSE
googlesheets4  0.1.1  1.0.0             FALSE
ggplot2        3.3.0  3.3.5             FALSE
haven          2.2.0  2.4.3              TRUE
hms            0.5.3  1.1.1             FALSE
jsonlite       1.6.1  1.7.2              TRUE
lubridate      1.7.8 1.7.10              TRUE
magrittr         1.5  2.0.1              TRUE
modelr         0.1.6  0.1.8             FALSE
pillar         1.4.3  1.6.3             FALSE
readr          1.3.1  2.0.2              TRUE
rlang          0.4.5 0.4.11              TRUE
rvest          0.3.5  1.0.1             FALSE
tibble         3.0.1  3.1.4              TRUE
tidyr          1.0.2  1.1.4              TRUE
tidyverse      1.3.0  1.3.1             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
Package which is only available in source form, and may need
  compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘tzdb’
  These will not be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/tidyselect_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 242507 bytes (236 KB)
downloaded 236 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/vctrs_0.2.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1018801 bytes (994 KB)
downloaded 994 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/glue_1.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 157284 bytes (153 KB)
downloaded 153 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/ellipsis_0.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 44220 bytes (43 KB)
downloaded 43 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/vroom_1.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1665604 bytes (1.6 MB)
downloaded 1.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/cli_2.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 397120 bytes (387 KB)
downloaded 387 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/dplyr_0.8.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3256479 bytes (3.1 MB)
downloaded 3.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/haven_2.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1050152 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/jsonlite_1.6.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1164207 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/lubridate_1.7.8.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1583751 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/magrittr_1.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 155738 bytes (152 KB)
downloaded 152 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/readr_1.3.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1588558 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/rlang_0.4.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1115838 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/tibble_3.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 407904 bytes (398 KB)
downloaded 398 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/tidyr_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1297802 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

package ‘tidyselect’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘glue’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘ellipsis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘vroom’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘haven’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘jsonlite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘lubridate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘magrittr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘readr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tibble’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘tidyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\arikl\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCoTyE0\downloaded_packages
installing the source packages ‘lifecycle’, ‘gargle’, ‘rematch2’, ‘scales’, ‘broom’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘dtplyr’, ‘googledrive’, ‘googlesheets4’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘hms’, ‘modelr’, ‘pillar’, ‘rvest’, ‘tidyverse’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 99716 bytes (97 KB)
downloaded 97 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gargle_1.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 313418 bytes (306 KB)
downloaded 306 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rematch2_2.1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 13366 bytes (13 KB)
downloaded 13 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/scales_1.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 515201 bytes (503 KB)
downloaded 503 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/broom_0.7.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 631606 bytes (616 KB)
downloaded 616 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dbplyr_2.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 581845 bytes (568 KB)
downloaded 568 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dtplyr_1.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 111895 bytes (109 KB)
downloaded 109 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/googledrive_2.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1593656 bytes (1.5 MB)
downloaded 1.5 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/googlesheets4_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 222038 bytes (216 KB)
downloaded 216 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.3.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3063309 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/hms_1.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 43117 bytes (42 KB)
downloaded 42 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/modelr_0.1.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 121333 bytes (118 KB)
downloaded 118 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pillar_1.6.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1130236 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rvest_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 94307 bytes (92 KB)
downloaded 92 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 702779 bytes (686 KB)
downloaded 686 KB

* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/lifecycle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'gargle' ...
** package 'gargle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.9 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'gargle'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/gargle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gargle’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'rematch2' ...
** package 'rematch2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'lifecycle'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'rematch2'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rematch2'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rematch2’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'broom' ...
** package 'broom' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'dplyr' 0.8.5 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'broom'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/broom'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/broom'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'scales'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/scales'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'dbplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/dbplyr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'dtplyr'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/dtplyr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dtplyr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'hms'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/hms'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package 'modelr' ...
** package 'modelr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'lifecycle'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'modelr'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/modelr'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/modelr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘modelr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'pillar'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/pillar'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'lifecycle' is not available for package 'rvest'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rvest'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'gargle', 'lifecycle', 'pillar' are not available for package 'googledrive'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/googledrive'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googledrive’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'scales' is not available for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ggplot2'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'gargle', 'googledrive', 'rematch2' are not available for package 'googlesheets4'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/googlesheets4'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘googlesheets4’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies 'dbplyr', 'dtplyr', 'googledrive', 'googlesheets4', 'ggplot2', 'hms', 'pillar', 'rvest' are not available for package 'tidyverse'
* removing 'C:/Users/arikl/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tidyverse'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\arikl\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCoTyE0\downloaded_packages’
> library(tidyverse)
Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very old version of R.  You should update to the current version if you want things to go smoothly.

If you can't do that, here's what you'll have to do:

- Install the version of Rtools suitable for R 3.5.x.
- Install the packages you want.  Some of them won't work, because they will need later versions of R, but won't declare that.  So when you find one that fails, try installing the previous version of that package.  If that also fails, try an even earlier one. Etc.  Your R version was current in 2018, so you may need to go that far back in time to find compatible packages.
- Once you finally have everything working, try to update your packages.  Maybe some of them could be more recent versions, maybe not.  Do them one at a time.  Typically `tidyverse` needs about 90 of them, so this will take a while.

So I recommend that you update your R version.

Comment: `remotes:install_version` should be handy for your second bullet (once the `remotes` package is installed).

Comment: Thank you I deleted old version of R from my computer and downloaded the latest version of R sharing the website for download of R 4.1.1 and it was able to install the tidyverse package now. to download version go here: https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/CRAN/

Answer (score 0):

On my macOS12, it prompts me to install `openssl` and then install `tinyverse` again